# "Fatal error encountered during command execution in mySql "

Tags: c#, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi9Ry.png)
i need to view this data in aster_user page to c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYb6X.png)
when i click edit link i get the update form to edit the datagridview row in database.

I have a Problem during MySQL in C#. I want update data in my MySQL Database.

```
        String MyCon =SERVER=********** +

        DATABASE=asterisk +

         UID=root +

         PASSWORD=**** + Convert Zero Datetime = True";

 private void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(MyCon);

        con.Open();

        string query = "UPDATE userid,password,role,first_name,last_name,user_group,user_level,active FROM aster_users" +
                       "SET password=@password,role=@role,first_name=@first_name,last_name=@last_name,user_level=@user_level,user_group=@user_group,active=@active" +
                       "WHERE userid=userid";
       MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pasword", txtconformpassword.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@role", cmbrole.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", txtfirstname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", txtlastname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_group", cmbUser1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_level", cmbuser.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@active", cmbstatus.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("updated......");
        con.Close();
    }
```

help me.. i had Fatal error encountered during command execution in cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); .

Comment: Maybe, one should use a space between UPDATE and userid ?

Comment: thank u for reply..  i leave space space between UPDATE and userid but it not work same error occurs.

Comment: Have you tried to use breakpoint and debug into the code just before the "Execute"? What does the build SQL look like?

Comment: You are concatenating the sql script but do not have whitespaces at the end of each part, thus your script should look like FROM aster_usersSET password=@ instead of FROM aster_users SET password=@

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my untrained eye, the construction of the sql statement looks dubious

```
string query = "UPDATE userid,password,role,first_name,last_name,user_group,user_level,active FROM aster_users" +
   "SET password=@password,role=@role,first_name=@first_name,last_name=@last_name,user_level=@user_level,user_group=@user_group,active=@active" +
   "WHERE userid=userid";
```

As it is a mySQL database one should be able to use backticks around field names, there were inconsistent spaces at end/ beginnings of lines and the `where clause` appears to need a variable `@userid` but is declared as a string?

```
string query = "UPDATE `aster_users` " +
   "SET `password`=@password, `role`=@role, `first_name`=@first_name, `last_name`=@last_name, `user_level`=@user_level, `user_group`=@user_group, `active`=@active " +
   "WHERE `userid`=@userid";
```